# Set tmux title to path

Tags: tmux

I'm currently setting tmux to update the window title to the name of the currently running command by doing the following:

```
set-option -g set-titles on
set-option -g set-titles-string '#S:#I.#P #W' # window number,program name,active (or not)
set-window-option -g automatic-rename on      # auto name
```

However, when no command is being executed, it just displays "N:zsh" (where N is the window number).

Is there a way to display the current last element of the path in the window title when no command is being executed?  So, if the current path is /usr/src/linux, the window title should be "N:linux".

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I have a semi-solution to show both:

```
# window titles
set-window-option -g window-status-current-format ' #[fg=white]** #[fg=white,bold][#{window_index}] #[fg=green]#{pane_current_command} #[fg=cyan]#(pwd="#{pane_current_path}"; echo ${pwd####*/}) #[fg=white]**'
set-window-option -g window-status-format '#[fg=colour244,bold][#{window_index}] #[fg=colour244]#{pane_current_command} #[fg=colour244]#(pwd="#{pane_current_path}"; echo ${pwd####*/})'
```

Add these lines into your `~/.tmux.conf` and would get:

[image]